# Twitter Bootstrap 3: How to center a block

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

It seems to me that the class `center-block` is missing from the bootstrap 3 style sheets.  Am I missing something?

Its usage is described here, http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center

Comment: can we see your work?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's new in the Bootstrap 3.0.1 release, so make sure you have the latest (10/29)...

Demo: http://bootply.com/91632

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="center-block" style="width:200px;background-color:#ccc;">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 19):

It works far better this way (preserving responsiveness):

```
  <!-- somewhere deep start -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="center-block col-md-4" style="float: none; background-color: grey">
      Hi there!
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- somewhere deep end -->
```

http://www.bootply.com/0L5rBI2taZ

Comment: works but give a horizontal scrollbar because of the row class. more info there https://www.dvdheiden.nl/2013/12/04/bootstrap-3-row-class-causes-horizontal-scrollbar/

Comment: You can use class `.center-block` in combination with `style="width:400px;max-width:100%;"` to preserve responsiveness.

Answer (score 11):

You have to use style="width:value" with center block class

Answer (score 3):

center-block can be found in bootstrap 3.0 in [utilities.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/44b32a30366440b2127b343fbd1990fe15e88185/less/utilities.less) on line 12
and [mixins.less](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/c6e76d97bab6f174f2f877433985cb11ff9368b1/less/mixins.less) on line 39

Answer (score 2):

You can use class `.center-block` in combination with `style="width:400px;max-width:100%;"` to preserve responsiveness.

Using `.col-md-*` class with `.center-block` will not work because of the `float` on `.col-md-*`.

Answer (score 1):

`center-block` is bad idea as it covers a portion on your screen and you cannot click on your fields or buttons.
`col-md-offset-?` is better option.

Use `col-md-offset-3`  is better option if class is `col-sm-6`. Just change the number to center your block.

Answer (score 1):

A few answers here seem incomplete. Here are several variations:

```
<style>
.box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 4px solid gray;
}
</style>    

<!-- This works: .container>.row>.center-block.box -->
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="center-block bg-primary box">This div is centered with .center-block</div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- This does not work -->    
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="center-block bg-primary box col-xs-4">This div is centered with .center-block</div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- This is the hybrid solution from other answers:
     .container>.row>.col-xs-6>.center-block.box
 -->   
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 bg-info">
                <div class="center-block bg-primary box">This div is centered with .center-block</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

To make it work with col-* classes, you need to wrap the .center-block inside a .col-* class, but remember to either add another class that sets the width (.box in this case), or to alter the .center-block itself by giving it a width.

Check it out on [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/2NtwEBNsEO).