# Regarding responsiveness of websites to small screens

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4, responsive

This is my first website,my portfolio's URL https://sarthak-port.000webhostapp.com/Mportfolio.html
I have used webhost for free hosting.My problem is I did use bootstrap classes in my code but my page is not fully responsive to small screens.Can you guys suggest some ideas to do the same.

Comment: This question would be better for the code review Community where you could post you code of the site and ask for responsiveness corrections. There you could get some better suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

From watching it a little bit you use in the space "My Works" and the space My Profiles only classes col-xs-3 for each element. If you want your sections to rearrange in a responsive matter you should probably use classes like

```
class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"
```

This way in larger screen widths you should have four 4 elements in every row then in smaller screen widths only 2 elements in every row and finally in very small screens only 1 element in every row. By setting all elements to col-xs-3 you demand four elements in every row in all screens.
Furthermore for the last section your input fields don't use bootstrap classes to set to middle. One way would be to use

```
col-md-6 col-md-3-offset
```

This way you can send your input to center (3 grid cells empty+6 grid cells with your input and 3 grid cells empty again)
Else you could use something like this [Twitter Bootstrap 3: How to center a block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758967/twitter-bootstrap-3-how-to-center-a-block).
Bootstrap has many classes that you can use but it needs some digging.