# Can't vertical centre an image in Bootstrap 3.x .col-md-12

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap 3.3.7

I can't get an image to appear vertical centre inside a `.col-md-12`. I've tried to use solutions from:

- [Twitter Bootstrap 3: How to center a block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758967/twitter-bootstrap-3-how-to-center-a-block)
- [How to align an image dead center with bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879955/how-to-align-an-image-dead-center-with-bootstrap)
- [How to vertically align an image inside a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div)

The markup is straightforward:

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <a href="#">About</a> | 
                <a href="#">Terms</a> |
                <a href="#">Privacy</a>

                <img class="pull-right hidden-xs hidden-sm" src="footer.jpg">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

The following CSS is applied to the footer:

```
.footer {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: red;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

I've tried:

1. Adding `.center-block` to the `img`. This does nothing.
2. Adding a `.frame` around the image as per [How to vertically align an image inside a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div) and adjusting the width/height values accordingly. This pushes the image "underneath" the footer on to a new row.

The natural image size is 265px wide and 30px high. So I assume there is enough height (50px) on the footer for this to work.

The image is appearing at the vertical top of the footer and is not in the middle:

[image]

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/0m3verv9/1/

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `center-block` works: https://jsfiddle.net/bsu9gq2q/3/ -- the line-height, height is hiding it.

Comment: My mistake, I meant *vertical* centre but had incorrectly used the word horizontal. I'm trying to do what's shown here, but within a `.col-md-12`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div

Comment: Marking this as a duplicate is wrong because the solution given on those pages doesn't work.

Comment: Many of the answers will work.. for example: https://jsfiddle.net/xcb7L12a/ -- you just need to figure out which approach you want to use flexbox, translateY, inline-block, table cell, etc.. Also consider that vertical center is always relative to the height of the container and the `col-md-12` had no defined height.

Comment: There are many different ways: https://jsfiddle.net/r8kLrepo/